# Output taxonomy term in views unformatted using twig

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8, theming

I'd like to output taxonomy terms as html classes for view-rows in the views unformatted template for Drupal 8.

My code:

```
    {% if title %}
       <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% for row in rows %}
       <div class="taxonomy-term-{{ term.id }}">
          <div{{ row.attributes }}>
             {{ row.content }}
          </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think we need more information about how your view is set up. I have a feeling it's not working because "term" may not be an available variable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You're a little light on details about your setup, but I can make a suggestion based on what I see. I don't know how you're settings the `term` variable, but `row` will have access to the node (assuming this is a node view) that represents the row being displayed. You can do something similar to

`{{ row.content['#node'].field_tags.getValue().0.target_id }}`

(assuming `field_tags` is your term reference field) to print the referenced term ID.

Edit: just realized how long ago this was asked... Not sure why it was showing at the top of my list. Anyhow, hopefully helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `<div class={{ row.attributes }}>`

Comment: actually <div{{ row.attributes }}> works just fine.   <div class="taxonomy-term-{{ term.id }}"> is what is giving me trouble

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy existing

> `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`

file from views module directory

> `core/modules/views/templates/views-view-unformatted.html.twig` (**As You already did**)

Then You need to **Add Field From (Taxonomy Term) View** in order to get that field's value in your twig's `{{ row }}` variable